# Extend array by repeating first row two times and stacking it to the front

Tags: arrays, numpy

Say I have a 2D array and I want to take the first row, repeat it two times and stack it to the front of the 2D array. My way to do this would be as follows:

```
test = np.array([[1,2],
                [3,4]])
np.hstack((np.repeat(np.atleast_2d(test[:,0]).T, 2, axis=1), test))
```

This looks rather complicated. Is there any simpler way to do it? I looked at `np.tile`, however this seems to keep the shape.

Comment: How about `np.c_[np.tile(test[:,[0]],2),test]`?

Comment: Although about three times slower, that's a cool alternative, thanks!

Comment: What dataset did you test it on?

Comment: Actually the `test` array from above...do you get different results?

Comment: Why are you looking for performance if your dataset has just 4 elements?

Comment: Well, two reasons: 1) If I have to perform the same thing on this small dataset a million times, or, 2) if my dataset gets bigger this could be of interest I guess, right? But anyway, I'm happy if you suggest this as an answer!